# Want to use categories as pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a couple of pages (home, about me, ...) in my main navigation. Now I'd like to get rid of my sidebar and I have plenty of space in my main navigation. Is there any chance I could get my categories to display in there, preferably with the subcategories displaying as childs (which will work well in the dropdown menu I have)?

Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php wp_list_cats(); ?>` will list your categories. It will however list them vertically so you'll need to use css in your style sheet to create a class to list the horizontally.

As for removing the side bar. If you go to your index.php and your single.php you will set something like `<?php sidebar(); ?>` or `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` by removing this the page will no longer fetch your side bar. I would personally not advise deleting the sidebar.php file(if you have one) or deleting this line of code for formatting reasons. It is probably best to comment it out that way you can add it back if you ever decide you want a sidebar again.

Comment: Thanks man, though not exactly what I needed. I need to know how to integrate these categories in my pages menu.

Comment: On a page if you want the categories listed just call the via the function `<?php wp_list_cats(); ?>`. If you want them in like say a drop down menu call them via the same function, then using css filter them into a drop down menu as separate(FYI when you call the categories I believe they are already links) entries just let sub-pages do. If your theme supports sub pages you can model the drop downs off of those. If you just want an extra bar across the top with the categories call them, build a span/div bar with css. Make the css arrange them horizontally. Hope this helps.